# iOS Firebase Image @2x @3x

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase

I have search all over internet, and cant find a solution.
How do you deal loading images from **Firebase** to support iOs **@2x** and **@3x** resolutions?

I know how to load an image from Firebase but not how to handle the different resolutions Issue.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to retrieve the PDF version of the resource a SVG version of it and manipulate it in iOS. Actually you cannot convert on the fly this kind of file, you need to convert it...

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful because it leaves out all of the important details.

Comment: I prefer PNG, there must be a workarround to solve this.